# QuickTime Player won't save edited file: The operation could not be completed

Tags: video, mojave, error, quicktime, video-editing

I've edited an MP4 movie file in Quicktime Player Version 10.5.

When I try to save the edited file, I get: The operation could not be completed.

Does anyone know what causes this and/or how it can be solved?

macOS Mojave 10.14.2 / Quicktime Player 10.5 / MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Comment: I have the same problem. Found out later the error code is "-12769".

Answer (score 2):

For me, the error came as I was editing in Quick-Time by right-clicking on the imported video in the Photos app.

Once I dragged the video (export) to a directory, and **then** edited the `.mp4` file, all was fine. No errors when Trimming and Saving.

Comment: Photos.app already supports trimming videos and can do a lot more. There’s no point in using QuickTime here.

Comment: The original post was about using QuickTime... So I thought this might be a useful bit of evidence for the OP to get something working. 

But thanks (?) for pointing that QuickTime is not needed, @fregante. 

Maybe you should make that an answer instead of a comment to my answer?

Comment: I can't seem to get photos to edit the video, i just need to trim it

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I downloaded a youtube video, opened in Quicktime to "trim" the video and quick time would not complete the operation. 
I ran the youtube video through Vlc Crunch (free video converter)as mp4 again and then Quicktime worked fine.

Comment: The point of using QuickTime is to *avoid downloading other software.* If you must use other software, just find one that allows trimming too. Saving the video from two apps makes it lose quality.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. It seems that QuickTime is able to handle the file via the **Share** feature but not the **Export**.

You can choose to **share to Messages** and then save the file from there, or use [Shareful](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shareful/id1522267256?mt=12), a small free app that lets you enable a "Save as" option in the Share menu.

[image: Share -> Save As…]

Comment: There was a time when these kind of discrepancies where unthinkable in Apple software … Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Guyz hello, i'm on High Sierra, i have that error "The operation could not be completed / Impossibile completare l'operazione", it happens often when i trim / cut a downloaded .mp4 video(same happened on el capitan), i think it cause there are small problems/errors after the download of a video, also if video is well played by Quick Time / VLC.
So i simply copy the downloaded video and paste it in another location, example - copy from download folder and paste to desktop. Then i can save the trimmed / cutted video. I think after copy in some magic way OSX corrects those small errors.
Hope it will work for you also! Have a nice day!^^

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer. But inform some important piece of information.

I encounter the same problem. The error code is "-12769"

Found out that there are some input videos which worked.

And when I compare both info of videos.

A video that's work :

[image: Good video]

A video that's doesn't :

[image: Bad video]

The only difference is encoding software between Lavf57.19.100 vs Lavf58.12.100

Comment: Have you tried more samples to make sure this isn’t a coincidence? You’d need a lot more samples, really, from a lot of different sources. There is more to a video file than what shows up in QuickTime’s Get Info pane. :)

Answer (score 0):

I get this error all the time as well (usually with error code -12780). I have a feeling it is related to files that have small errors (like missing keyframes, or a videotrack that is out of sync with the audiotrack).

Unfortunately the only solution i have found thus far is re-encoding the video and trying again (using a tool like ffmpeg or Handbrake) or using editing software like Premiere Pro / iMovie / Final Cut. In both cases, you need to re-encode the video and it will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I will answer it for others having the same issue. (Added note: I just realized my error is slightly different - it won't save because I don't have permission).
I just solved it by changing the folder it's saved to. It was defaulting to my Mac hard drive and for some reason would not save there. I changed it to another folder and it saved just fine. Hope this helps someone.